# Como dar scroll automaticamente na page usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, rolamento

Estou desenvolvendo uma tela aonde tem um passo a passo e utilizo slideUP e slideDown fechar e abrir as divs relacionadas aos mesmos.

Como faço para o scroll da page acompanhar automaticamente quando desço uma?

Comment: Semelhante ao uso de links ancoras?

Comment: Exatamente, seria algo similar. É um formulário e de acordo com que cada pergunta é respondida uma se esconde e desce a próxima. Nisso quero fazer a page acompanhar também, entende?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar essa função do JavaScript, quando fazer o último passo da tela.
`window.scrollTo(xpos, ypos);`
 Ex:

`function onFinish(){
    window.scrollTo(40, 0);
}`

Comment: Como eu encontro essa posição correta dos eixos x e y? Eu usei algo similar e funcionou, mas não como queria devido exatamente a isso. Como saber posicionar certinho. Consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Com jQuery vc consegue pegar essas posições da div
`var p = $( "yourDiv" );
var position = p.position();
position.left;
position.top;`